# How do I sort by a rolled up group?

Tags: sorting, sql-server-2008-r2, grouping

Let's say I have a table in SQL Server 2008 R2 called `Purchase` with two columns: `Purchaser` and  `Expenditure`.

Let's say that the table has the following rows:

```
Purchaser    Expenditure
---------    -----------
Alex         200
Alex         300
Alex         500
Bob          300
Bob          400
Charlie      200
Charlie      600
Derek        100
Derek        300
```

Now I have this query:

`SELECT Purchaser, Expenditure, SUM(Expenditure) AS SumExpenditure FROM Purchase GROUP BY Purchaser, Expenditure WITH ROLLUP`

This returns the following:

```
Purchaser    Expenditure    SumExpenditure
---------    -----------    --------------
Alex         200            200
Alex         300            300
Alex         500            500
--------------------------------
Alex         NULL           1000
--------------------------------
Bob          300            300
Bob          400            400
--------------------------------
Bob          NULL           700
--------------------------------
Charlie      200            200
Charlie      600            600
--------------------------------
Charlie      NULL           800
--------------------------------
Derek        100            100
Derek        300            300
--------------------------------
Derek        NULL           400
--------------------------------
```

(Lines added to emphasise the rolled up amounts.)

What I would like would be to be able to sort the groups by the grouped amounts so that I end up with a result set like this:

```
Purchaser    Expenditure    SumExpenditure
---------    -----------    --------------
Derek        100            100
Derek        300            300
--------------------------------
Derek        NULL           400
--------------------------------
Bob          300            300
Bob          400            400
--------------------------------
Bob          NULL           700
--------------------------------
Charlie      200            200
Charlie      600            600
--------------------------------
Charlie      NULL           800
--------------------------------
Alex         200            200
Alex         300            300
Alex         500            500
--------------------------------
Alex         NULL           1000
--------------------------------
```

In other words, I am sorting the groups, using the `400`, `700`, `800` and `1000` in the group rows by ascending order.

Can anyone suggest what query would return this result set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
;WITH x AS 
(
    SELECT Purchaser, Expenditure, s = SUM(Expenditure) 
    FROM dbo.Purchase 
    GROUP BY Purchaser, Expenditure WITH ROLLUP
),
y AS 
(
    SELECT Purchaser, s FROM x 
    WHERE Expenditure IS NULL
    AND Purchaser IS NOT NULL
),
z AS 
(
    SELECT Purchaser, s, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY s)
    FROM y
)
SELECT x.Purchaser, x.Expenditure, x.s FROM x 
INNER JOIN z ON x.Purchaser = z.Purchaser
ORDER BY z.rn, CASE WHEN z.s IS NULL THEN 2 ELSE 1 END;
```